# Instabug dismiss intro dialog after a couple of seconds

Tags: android, timer, dialog, dismiss, instabug

This is how I initiate instabug:

```
  Instabug.DEBUG = true;
    instabug = Instabug.initialize(this)
            .setAnnotationActivityClass(InstabugAnnotationActivity.class)
            .setShowIntroDialog(true, PSTimelineActivity.class)
            .enableEmailField(true, false)
            .setEnableOverflowMenuItem(true)
            .setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setCommentRequired(true)
            .setPostFeedbackMessage(getString(titleID) + getString(R.string.feedback_confirmation_subtitle))
            .setPostBugReportMessage(getString(titleID) + getString(R.string.feedback_confirmation_subtitle)) //TODO will be the post report message, random from array
            .setCommentFieldHint("Please describe what went wrong")
```

As you can see, I set it to show the intro dialog BUT my issue is that if the user doesn't press the screen, it will not be dismissed. Is it possible to dismiss the dialog after a couple of seconds?

Comment: hi! did you find the answer of this??

Comment: nope :( let me know if you find something